# Jupyter Notebook - Import Torch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and tried downloading and installing Pytorch using Anaconda. It downloads successfully, however when I want to start writing in a new Jupyter Notebook, something isn't right. I installed Pytorch with CUDA 10.2. In my Jupyter Notebook, I type "import torch" to let the notebook know that I want to use Pytorch. But, it keeps giving me this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-eb42ca6e4af3> in <module>
----> 1 import torch

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py in <module>
     79     dlls = glob.glob(os.path.join(th_dll_path, '*.dll'))
     80     for dll in dlls:
---> 81         ctypes.CDLL(dll)
     82 
     83 

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

When I type "conda list" in my Anaconda Prompt, I see that Pytorch and torchvision are both installed. But not torch. Can anyone help me figure out this problem? 
Also, when I try installing Pytorch without CUDA, it runs fine, but I want to include CUDA when I'm running my programs. Is there a way to download Pytorch without it, and then import it?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: is the jupyter notebook using the python version that belongs to anaconda?

Comment: In anaconda terminal (command line) make sure you are in the correct environment you installed the pytorch on (by default its "base"), and then launch jupyter from the same anaconda terminal.